# how to add angular 2 to exist ASP .NEt core app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, angular, asp.net-core

I saw a lot of guides how to add angular 2 to my project but all of them where very large and no 1 didn't work.
mb someone know simple way to add angular 2 to my .NET core app? Now i am using VS 2015.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend you upgrade to visual studio 2017. In VS 2017 .Net Core and standard .Net incompatibilities were resolved. But back to your question I found a very nice angular 2 template for c# .Net Core:

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/

This will help you setup your project structure and give you the head start you need.

Comment: Thank you for answer so quick but i have an existing and working project. i can't use this template to setup any changes.